# Is it possible to disable CPU/Laptop fan through Device Manager?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cpu-cooler

My laptop's a bit old now and it's fan is very noisy now, I don't have time or money yet to either open, clean or get this to repair shop rn, it's not a n option for me right now? It also frequently stops and doesn't run even on startup, maybe bc it's stucked or something but when the laptop gets moved, it starts to run again. ***Is it possible to disable the fans through Device Manager by disabling like the driver that makes it run?*** Besides, I got a real electric fan beside my laptop right now, and the climate's cold so it's working and well ventilated. I need to disable it so I can't hear this loud noise again and able to work on this laptop again? Is it possible? Any way?

Comment: Even if you were outside, in arctic weather, without airflow generated by the fan your computer would overheat within minutes.  Wouldn't it be easier to just purchase the $5 part and replace it?  Since your laptop does not have a  fan controller, you will be unable to turn off the fan, with the hardware you have.  The fan in question, does not have a device driver, you will be unable to disable it within Device Manager.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible through Device Manager.  Some BIOSes will allow you to throttle it, but I've never seen one that will allow you to turn it off completely due to overheating.

You should always run the internal fan as it removes heat from the CPU, without which, the CPU would fry.  I recommend getting some compressed air and blowing out the fan/vents.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent your computer from overheating as much by setting the maximum processor frequency to a lower amount and changing the system cooling policy to passive to prevent your laptop fans from turning on in your Power plan in Control Panel. You might need to change the registry value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\CSenabled` from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be able to control the fan through the device manager. Computer fans don't have drivers the same way that a mouse or keyboard does.

Some fans do provide support for changing the speed or disabling the fan though. If your computer supports that, you should be able to turn the fans off or down low with a utility such as [speedfan.](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

That being said, I would **strongly** advise that you do not ever do this. Seriously, you'll burn out your CPU in no time. It doesn't matter how cold it is in the room, if it's not designed for passive cooling it **will** overheat in short order without air flow. You would be much better off spending the 15 minutes it would take to clean out or replace the fan. Or if you really can't be bothered, at least go buy a can of air duster and blow the fans and heatsinks out. You don't even need to open the case.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. If you're going to downvote please let me know why in the comments so I can fix the answer.